# Random Tensor Generation with maximum and minimum values

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I create a Variable in **Tensorflow** like:

```
   W=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,100]))
```

Is there any way to give the random generated values a maximum and minimum value?

I have problems with the start-configuration of my network and I think it is because there are too big random values.

Has `tf.random_normal` such an option?

Answer (score 2):

No, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) there is no such option in `tf.random_normal`. That would also be a bit unusual as the normal distribution is specified by a mean and a variance parameter only. If you crop it at some point, you'd have to think about re-normalization, how to draw random numbers, and stuff like this.

However, if you want to decrease the size of your initial parameters, just reduce the mean (you set to `10`) and the variance (you set to `100`)-- they're anyways quite large in my opinion.

Moreover, you can have a look at `tf.random_uniform` with approproiately specified boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you suspect that `tf.random_normal` generates high values, then you can clip the values using [`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value). Rest available options are listed by @davidhigh.